# How can I take rows to the TXT file in the method?

Tags: java, file

How can I print the line in the txt file drawn in the `void txt()` method, inside the `driver.get()` parentheses in `void link()` with quotes?

I want to get a link from the txt file and let the automatic program enter the site.

Thanks for your help.

```
package test2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

    public class test2 {

                        public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                        public Actions action = new Actions(driver);

                        public static String rows = "";

    public void link() throws InterruptedException { 

            // driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        //How can I type here,taken row from the TXT file in the quotes("")?
            driver.get(rows);
                Thread.sleep(3000);     
        }

    public void txt() throws IOException {

        // open the LinkAl txt file
        File file = new File("LinkAl.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int i=0;
        rows = reader.readLine();

            while (rows!=null) {
                i++;
                 // Get the second row to the LinkAl txt file
                if(i==2)
                {
                    System.out.println(rows);
                }
                rows = reader.readLine();
            }
        }   

    public void driverquit() { 

            driver.quit();
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException { 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            test2 Links = new test2();

            // Links.link();
            Links.txt();
            Links.driverquit();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your below method like mentioned to read file line by line till EOF.

```
 public void txt() throws IOException {

        // open the LinkAl txt file
        File file = new File("LinkAl.txt");
        String line="";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    // System.out.println(line);
                       link(line);

            }
        }
```

Also if you want to pass the read line to link method change it as below

```
public void link(String line) throws InterruptedException { 

          System.out.println("Dosyadançekilenlerveriler: " + line);

            // driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
           driver.get(line);
             Thread.sleep(3000);     
        }
```

Comment: Hi,,, EOF mean?

Comment: EOF means end of file